# Как получить записи из таблиц, связанных через другую таблицу Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Например, есть таблица с авторами, таблица с произведениями, таблица с цитатами.
Первая связана со второй (один ко многим), вторая с третьей (один ко многим)
Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно получить все цитаты конкретного автора в laravel через eloquent.
Таблицы, называются stories, novels, quotes

Comment: Приведите описание моделей и связей кодом в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибся при написании названий таблиц (authors, stories, quotes). Вот рабочий вариант

```
$result=App\Author::join('stories', 'stories.author_id', '=','authors.id')
    ->join('quotes', 'quotes.story_id', '=','stories.id')
    ->where('authors.id',$author_id)->get();
```